# Simplify $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i}^{n-1}1$

Tags: summation

Question:

Simplify $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i}^{n-1}1$$

My attempt:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i}^{n-1}1 =\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (n-1-i) $$.

Would this now be the sum of the first $n-1$ integers?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thats strange because my textbook says that it is equal to sum of the first $n$ integers

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} n-1-i$ is the sum of the first $n-1$ positive integers and zero. However, $\sum_{j=i}^{n-1} 1\ne n-1-i$. In general, if $a\le b$, $\sum_{k=a}^b 1=b-a+1$.

Comment: How should I figure what the nested sum is equal to?

Comment: You should just realize it.

Comment: My guess is $n-i$ ?

Comment: A sum of 1's means counting. How many pairs of indices $(i,j)$ are there such that $0 \leq i \leq j \leq n-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of integers from $1$ to $m$ would be $m$. It can be computed by $m-1+\color{red}{1}$.

The number of integer from $i$ to $n-1$ would be $(n-1)-i+1=n-i$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i}^{n-1}1 =\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (n-1-i+\color{red}{1})= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (n-i)$$

When $i=0$, $n-i=n$.

When $i=n-1$, $n-i=n-(n-1)=1$.

Hence we are adding from $1$ to $n$ in the backward direction.

There is a special formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n i$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i}^{n-1}1&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{j}1
&&\scriptsize(0\le i\le j\le n-1)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(j+1)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n j\\
&=\color{red}{\frac 12n(n+1)=\binom {n+1}2}\end{align} $$

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i}^{n-1}1 $ counts the elements of $\{(i,j)\in\{0,..,n-1\}^2: i\leq j\}$

From the set $\{0,..,n-1\}$, there are $\underline{\phantom{\binom{n}2}}$ ways to select two distinct elements ($i<j$), and $\underline{\phantom{\binom n1}}$ ways to select two identical indices ($i=j$).

$$\therefore\qquad\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum\limits_{j=i}^{n-1}1 ~= \dbinom{n+1}2$$

Answer (score 0):

Put the sequence in a matrix, you have a $n\times n$ matrix, the first row is full of 1's the second row 1's except the first position, and so on... if you sum through columns you should have the sequence of the first $n$ integers.